# egrep regex -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, regex

Using egrep from command line with regex does not work and I get the error in the title.

```
egrep -rnw /var/log/usres/([a-z]+).([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+).conf/user.settings -e "pattern"
```

I have verified the regex over at https://regex101.com/r/pL5pW4/1 and used shellcheck.net and both say no problems. What I am trying to do is match  particular folders like this:

```
egrep -rnw /var/log/users/sd.dfr/test.conf/user.settings, so the
```

"sd.dfr" and the "test" in this example are what the regex is for. To match any combinations in those to folder paths. I've tried quoting, escaping, double quoting. Why is this not working?

Comment: That regex is being interpreted by `bash`, not `egrep`. If it's really important that you use a regex for globbing, you might look into `shopt -s extglob` to enable extended pattern matching.

Comment: Is `user.settings` a file or a directory?

Comment: user.setttings is a file

Answer (score 0):

`grep` searches for regular expressions *in the contents* of files.  It does not search for *files whose names match* regular expressions.  (Use `find` for that.)  Further, before grep sees them, the list of file/directory names that you supply is interpreted by the shell.  The shell matches files using  *globs* not regexes.

Shell globs are not as precise as regular expressions, but the following might work well enough for you:

```
egrep -rnw /var/log/users/*.*/*.conf/user.settings -e "pattern"
```

Or, better yet, because `egrep` is deprecated:

```
grep -Ernw /var/log/users/*.*/*.conf/user.settings -e "pattern"
```

Comment: I have been using wildcards and they work fine. The reason for the regex was I was looking into incorporating that into a shell script, in which case wildcards would not work for my application. I'll need to look for other solutions I suppose. The fact that these checked out on the regex site and shell checker and did not work from the command line had me very confused.

Comment: @user53029 If you want to select files with a regex, not a glob, use `find -regex`.